# Manually verify keyloak access token

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I would like to manually verify access token in my service app. I found out that I should use `BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator`, but it need whole `HttpFacade` for authentication. Is there another way to manually authenticate access token or on the other hand obtain `HttpFacade` from controller.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try Keycloak's [AdapterTokenVerifier](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/rotation/AdapterTokenVerifier.java) instead.